# Is it wrong to say "from whence"?

Tags: meaning

I've heard "from whence it came" said many times, often when the writer is attempting to be formal (or is in fact formal). But the [definition](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/06/the-word-whence-is-pretty-much-always-used-incorrectly/) of *whence* is "from what place, source, or cause" (with "from" being the key word). So is it wrong to say "from whence it came"?

Comment: Please try to quote the source more completely -- the sentence, the para or the passage, along with a link to it. I can always say grammatically '**From whence it came** to where it came from, English language has changed a lot'.

Comment: And I was actually searching for the quote used by the OP of that question. So there.

Comment: Fine, then. The question may be closed as a duplicate in that case.

Comment: @Dodgie: the quote in that question is linked to in the question itself. It's from a YouTube video.